# How to pre-fill customer details(credit card, billing info, etc) in PayPal checkout?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jsx, paypal

I know Iam pretty new to this. I am using React to build the Paypal Button. I wonder how can I pass the customer data (first name, last name, billing address, credit card info, etc.) and pre-fill the checkout page?

I looked at the Paypal developer doc, but couldn't find solutions.

For credit card I saw it mentioned about paypal Vault. But I can't find any examples and don't know how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Here is my code in JSX:

```
import paypal from 'paypal-checkout';

class PayPalButton extends React.Component {
const client = {
  sandbox: ''
  production: ''
};

let payment = () => {
    ...
};

const onAuthorize = (data, actions) => {
    ...
};

const env = 'sandbox';

const style = {
  ...
};

let PayPalButton = paypal.Button.driver('react', { React, ReactDOM });

return (
  <div>
    <PayPalButton
      env={env}
      client={client}
      style={style}
      payment={payment}
      commit={true}
      onAuthorize={onAuthorize}
      onCancel={this.props.onCancel}
    />
  </div>
);
export default PayPalButton;
```

Comment: did you get answer ?